# Default constructor error no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, class

In `main()`, I am making an array `myAppointments`, and realize to make it work I would need to create a default constructor in `Appointments.h`, but when I do I get this error:

```
no matching function for call to 'Time::Time()'
Appointment(){
```

Here is Main:

```cpp
/*
 * Homework 4  -- UPDATE as needed
*/ 
    
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
    
#include "Appointment.h"
using namespace std;
    
void callPrint (Time &TimeOrApptObject) { TimeOrApptObject.print(); }

int main(){
    int month, day, year, hour, minute,howLong;
    Appointment  myAppointments[19];
    
    ifstream HW4DataFileHandle;
    
    HW4DataFileHandle.open("Lab6Data.txt");
    while (!HW4DataFileHandle.eof( )) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
            HW4DataFileHandle>>month;
            HW4DataFileHandle>>day;
            HW4DataFileHandle>>year;
            HW4DataFileHandle>>hour;
            HW4DataFileHandle>>minute;
            HW4DataFileHandle>>howLong;
            myAppointments[i] = Appointment( month, day, year, hour, minute, howLong);
        }
        cout <<"enter a month" <<endl;
        cin >> month;
        cout <<"enter a day" <<endl;
        cin >> day;
        cout <<"enter a year"<<endl;
        cin >> year;
        Date myDate( month, day, year);
    
        cout <<"Appointments for" << month <<"/" << day <<"/" << year <<":"<< endl;
    
        for (int i = 0; i <13; i++){
            if ( myAppointments[i]==Date myDate )
            {
                Time thisTime = myAppointments[i];
                thisDate.print();
                cout << endl;
            } 
        }
    }
```

And here are the header files:

Date.H

```cpp
// Date.h -- Class Date    UPDATE  as needed
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

class Date  {  
private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
public:
    Date(int m, int d, int y) : month(m), day(d), year(y)
    {
    }

    friend bool friendTorCompare2Dates (const Date&,const Date& );
};

bool friendTorCompare2Dates (const Date& Right, const Date& Left)
{
    if (Right.month == Left.month && Right.day == Left.day )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
    
#endif
```

Time.H

```cpp
//Time.h -- Class Time UPDATE  as needed
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H

class Time {
private :
    int hour; int minute;
public:
    Time(int h, int m) : hour(h)
    {
    }
    virtual void print() {
        cout << hour << " " << minute <<" "  ;
    }
};

#endif
```

Appointment.h

```cpp
// Appointment.h -- Class Appointment   UPDATE as needed
//
    
using namespace std;
#include "Time.h"
#include "Date.h"
#ifndef APPOINTMENT_H
#define APPOINTMENT_H

class Appointment:  public Date, public Time {  
private:
    int howLong;
public:
    Appointment(int month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute, int howLong) : 
        Date(month, day, year), Time(hour, minute), howLong(howLong)
    {
    }

    Appointment(){
        month;
        day;
        year;
        hour;
        minute;
        howLong;    
    }
};
        
#endif
```

What do I need to change in order to have my default constructor in `Appointment` work? If you notice any thing else, or have any other questions in regards to my question, please let me know. I would appreciate it if you would include an example in your answer.

Comment: `Appointment()` needs to call the base-class constructors, which do not have parameterless constructors. You need to figure out with what "default values" this constructor should call them

Comment: I will now repeat my warning about `while (!HW4DataFileHandle.eof( ))`. [It's a bug you'll find later.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Your header guards in `Time.H` and `Appointment.h` are not setup properly.  The `#ifndef ... #define ...` part needs to be at the very top.  All of the `#include` and `using namespace std;` statements need to be inside the `ifndef ... #endif` block

Comment: @MRHones you will have to write a `==` operator overload. Some help on doing that here: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
Appointment  myAppointments[19];
```

will call the default constructor of `Appointment` for each element.

Your default constructor doesn't explicitly call a constructor of `Time`, so the default constructor of `Time` will be called, which doesn't exist. Same with `Date`.

You can reinstate the default constructor like this:

```
class Time {
 // ...
 public:
  Time() = default;
};
```

To get reasonable default behavior, you should provide default initial values for the members of your class, e.g.

```
class Time {
 private :
   int hour = 0; 
   int minute = 0;
public:
   // ...
};
```

Comment: Ha! It's Baaaa-ack! Can't keep a good answer down, eh?

Comment: @user4581301 Haha, yeah, I thought OP was actually asking this originally, and figured they'd get around to it eventually ;)

Comment: Asker dropped a comment asking about this problem in the last question, so I pointed them at your answer only to find it had been deleted. Then they deleted the comment, and I figured the same as you. It'd show up sooner or later.

Comment: @user4581301 Edited the answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the array `Appointment myAppointments[19];`, the default constructor for `Appointment` is used immediately for all 19 elements.  However, `Date` and `Time` do not have default constructors defined, but `Appointment`'s default constructor will try to call them both implicitly, hence the error you are seeing since they don't exist.

So, you have 4 different ways to fix this:

1. make `Appointment`'s default constructor call `Date`'s and `Time`'s non-default constructors explicitly (just like your other `Appointment` constructor does), passing in default values to them:

   ```cpp
   Appointment() : 
       Date(0, 0, 0), Time(0, 0), howLong(0)
   {
   }
   ```
2. give `Date` and `Time` their own default constructors, eg:

   ```cpp
   class Date  {  
   private:
       int month;
       int day;
       int year;
   public:
       Date() : month(0), day(0), year(0)
       {
       }

       Date(int m, int d, int y) : month(m), day(d), year(y)
       {
       }

       ...
   };
   ```

   ```cpp
   class Time {
   private :
       int hour;
       int minute;
   public:
       Time() : hour(0), minute(0)
       {
       }

       Time(int h, int m) : hour(h), minute(m)
       {
       }

       ...
   };
   ```

   Alternatively:

   ```cpp
   class Date  {  
   private:
       int month;
       int day;
       int year;
   public:
       Date(int m = 0, int d = 0, int y = 0) : month(m), day(d), year(y)
       {
       }

       ...
   };
   ```

   ```cpp
   class Time {
   private :
       int hour;
       int minute;
   public:
       Time(int h = 0, int m = 0) : hour(h), minute(m)
       {
       }

       ...
   };
   ```

   Alternatively (C++11 and later only):

   ```cpp
   class Date  {  
   private:
       int month = 0;
       int day = 0;
       int year = 0;
   public:
       Date() = default;
       // or:
       // Date() : Date(0, 0, 0) {}

       Date(int m, int d, int y) : month(m), day(d), year(y)
       {
       }

       ...
   };
   ```

   ```cpp
   class Time {
   private :
       int hour = 0;
       int minute = 0;
   public:
       Time() = default;
       // or:
       // Time() : Time(0, 0) {}

       Time(int h, int m) : hour(h), minute(m)
       {
       }

       ...
   };
   ```
3. construct the array elements explicitly using [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) so you can use `Appointment`'s non-default constructor on them, eg:

   ```cpp
   typedef unsigned char AppointmentBuf[sizeof(Appointment)];
   // better:
   // #include <type_traits>
   // using AppointmentBuf = std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Appointment), alignof(Appointment)>::type;

   int main(){
       AppointmentBuf myAppointments[19];

       ...

       for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
           ...
           new (&myAppointments[i]) Appointment(month, day, year, hour, minute, howLong);
       }

       ...

       for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
           Appointment &appt = reinterpret_cast<Appointment&>(myAppointments[i]);
           // use appt as needed...
       }

       ...

       // cleanup
       for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
           reinterpret_cast<Appointment&>(myAppointments[i]).~Appointment();
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```
4. Change the array to hold `Appointment*` pointers, and then construct the array elements dynamically via [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) using `Appointment`'s non-default constructor, eg:

   ```cpp
   int main(){
       Appointment* myAppointments[19] = {};

       ...

       for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
           ...
           myAppointments[i] = new Appointment(month, day, year, hour, minute, howLong);
       }

       ...

       for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
           // use myAppointments[i] as needed...
       }

       ...

       // cleanup
       for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
           delete myAppointments[i];
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Alternatively (C++11 or later only):

   ```cpp
   #include <memory>

   int main(){
       std::unique_ptr<Appointment> myAppointments[19];

       ...

       for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
           ...
           myAppointments[i] = std::make_unique<Appointment>(month, day, year, hour, minute, howLong);
       }

       ...

       for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
           // use myAppointments[i] as needed...
       }

       ...

       // no manual cleanup needed

       return 0;
   }
   ```